# Validation of JAX-RS request with JAX-B object as parameter

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf

I try to validate a JAX-RS request with a JAX-B object as parameter.

**Code:**

JAX-B model class:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.test.com/test")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestModel {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}
```

JAX-RS resource class:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {
    
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public void create(TestModel testModel) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

CXF configuration:

```XML
<jaxrs:server address="/rest" id="test" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**Example:**

Request body:

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:testModel xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/test">
    <name>testName</name>
</ns2:testModel>
```

The `id` is missing, so I should get a [HTTP status 400](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), but I get [HTTP status 204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

**Research:**

I found [Schema validation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Schemavalidation):

> 1. Using jaxrs:schemaLocations element
>
> [...]
>
> 2. Configuring providers individually
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Using SchemaValidation annotation

but I have no XSD file (only JAX-B classes).

Is there a way to validate the JAX-B object without a XSD file?

Comment: If you're using CXF 3.x, it support [bean validation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-BeanValidation). Too bad the link in the documentation is a dead link. I don't use CXF so I can't really be of much help in configuring this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bad workaround is to generate XSD file with Maven:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>schemagen</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and add XSD files to CXF configuration:

```xml
<jaxrs:schemaLocations>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:schema1.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
    <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:schema2.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
</jaxrs:schemaLocations>
```